# geom_vline for values over a threshold on Y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot of temperature values plotted against time. I'd like to add vertical lines to my graph where temperature exceeds a threshold (let's say 12 degrees).

reprex:

```
#example data
Temp <- c(10.55, 11.02, 6.75, 12.55, 15.5)
Date <- c("01/01/2000", "02/01/2000", "03/01/2000", "04/01/2000", "05/01/2000")

#data.frame
df1 <- data.frame(Temp, Date)

#plot
df1%>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, format(as.numeric(Temp))))+
  geom_line(group=1)
```

I thought I could maybe do something with `geom_hline` and then rotate 90 degrees. I went about this by trying to create an `object` of all values (to 2dp) between 12 and 20. I would then tell `geom_hline` to use that `object` to match values and draw the lines.

Then I get a bit stuck. I don't really know how to rotate the lines or whether that's even a good idea.

Disclaimer: I know my dates are not actually dates in the reprex, but they are in my rle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_vline` can accept an xintercept either

- in the `xintercept` parameter (if you want to specify it manually) or
- in `aes(xintercept = ...)` if you want to use values from a data frame. We can use `data = . %>% filter...` to use the same data frame that came into ggplot, but apply some further manipulations.

---

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Temp)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(data = . %>% filter(Temp > 12),
             aes(xintercept = Date))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. My final output is a ```ggplotly``` graph and the vertical lines weren't showing up. For others who have this exact issue, just use ```as.numeric``` on the ```Date``` variable. It's a bug in ```plotly``` but this is a fix I found.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have vertical lines starting from the level of 12:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(Date, as.numeric(Temp)))+
  geom_line(group=1) +
  geom_segment(data= df1[df1$Temp>12,], 
               aes(x = Date, 
                   xend  = Date, 
                   y = 12, 
                   yend = Temp),
               color = "blue", lwd = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid not in this case, but I'll definitely be coming back to use that another time!